# Linked Google Sheet requires authorization although public

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have made a Google Sheet that links to another Google Sheet, using `IMPORTRANGE()`. Although the linked sheet has Public accessibility, I am still required to authorize access to the linked sheet.
Why is that?

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate or add some details (what you want to achieve, what type of link between sheets, etc..) ? 
For what it's woth, when using `IMPORTRANGE` you must explicitly grant permission [(source : importrange documentation)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).
Related Q&A : 
1.  [IMPORTRANGE connect sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130078/importrange-connect-sheets)

2.  [Automatically “Allow Access” for IMPORTRANGEs in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98202/222777)

Comment: I wonder what is the criteria behind this. If a sheet is shared with "anyone with the link", this means the sheet may be accessed by anyone. Period. Why now GAS requires additional auth. process?

Comment: My guess is maybe google doesn't want people to abuse the tool. (I dunno, there's like a ton of way of achieving that. First that come to mind is automate scraping at mass scale with 1000+sheets for free)

Comment: Questions about company internal policies, app design decisions, etc.  are off-topic on this site.